# Load json/mysql content lists based on nav menu ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

So I have a list of resources, or contact information, many for each 'specialty'.

On a left navigation menu I want to create a list of the 'specialties' and when the specialty is clicked, the list of relevant contact information will be shown on on the content area.

Sounds simple, but I am a beginner and am looking for the right/most efficient way to accomplish this.

Here is what the source data would look like (which is better? csv/json/mysql)

```
Table: people
┌────┬────────────────────┬─────────┬───────────┐─────────┐
| id | specialty| name    | phone   | url       | address |
├────┼────────────────────┼─────────┤───────────┐─────────┐
| 0  | One     | this     | blah    | www.x.com | 123 a st
| 1  | One     | that     | blah    | www.x.com | 123 b st
| 2  | One     | there    | blah    | www.x.com | 123 c st
| 3  | Two     | the      | blah    | www.x.com | 123 d st
| 4  | Two     | other    | blah    | www.x.com | 123 e st
└────┴────────────────────┴─────────┘───────────┘─────────┘
```

**Here's a JFIDDLE of the basic layout: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jwte0xp9/)**

So I have the data and layout done but completely lost when it comes with implementing this the right (simplest) way.

All help is greatly appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: Can you please share your json array as well?

Comment: Getting data from mysql as json is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

The menu HTML should be empty (no li items inside the ul), you will populate it from JS.

Travel the data array and get the different specialties:

```
var specialties = [], x;
for (x = 0; x < sampleData.length; ++x)
{
    if ($.inArray(sampleData[x].specialty, specialties) < 0)
        specialties.push(sampleData[x].specialty);
}
```

For each specialty you create a li element and append it to the ul. This li element will store the specialty name in a custom data-specialty attribute and will have a onclick event attached:

```
var ul = $("#menu");
  for (x = 0; x < specialties.length; ++x)
  {
    var li = $(document.createElement("li"));
    li.addClass("list-group-item");
    li.attr("data-specialty", specialties[x]);
    li.html(specialties[x]);
    li.on("click", specialtyClicked);
    ul.append(li);
  }
```

The onclick function travels the data array and generates HTML with the specialists of that specialty, that HTML code is then injected in the #contacts div:

```
function specialtyClicked()
{
    // Remove active attribute from all menu items and add it to this one
  $(".list-group-item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

    // Get the specialty name
    var specialty = $(this).attr("data-specialty");

  // Create the HTML for the specialists
  var output = "<h2>" + specialty + "</h2><br/>";
  for (x = 0; x < sampleData.length; ++x)
  {
    var s = sampleData[x];
    if (s.specialty != specialty)
        continue;

    output += "<h4>" + s.name + "</h4><p>" + s.address + "<br/>" + s.phone + " - " + s.url + "</p>";
  }
  $("#contacts").html(output);
}
```

Here's a full working commented example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvq8a9me/8/ I think it's easier to understand when you see the code.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. What would need to be altered for mysql instead of json?

Comment: You can create an array of arrays in PHP with all the data, then use json_encode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate a JSON object. In JS, use JSON.parse (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to convert the JSON string to a JS object.